# Astronaut crashing on a planet full of robots and a weapon factory

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short SF story that I read in the late 1970s or early 1980s. The narrative was in English. I read it from a hardcover book. I am quite sure it was a compilation of science fiction stories. I've pieced together memories from the reading. By that time, I was a teenager.

The plot revolved around a female astronaut whose spaceship was forced to change course due to a fault (I believe it was in the navigation or communication systems) caused by the magnetic field of an unknown planet located outside our solar system, forcing the ship to land on the planet. I'm not certain, but I believe the spacecraft was returning to Earth.

The planet was made of an unknown metal and was barren save from occasional exploding plumes on the surface. The astronaut and her mission partner, an AI robot, driving a rover, set out to explore the planet's surface, where they discovered an immense metallic mound with a massive door open. It looked that the door had been opened for ages. The inside of the mound was filled with hollow passageways. They followed a path illuminated by torches with a non-burning fire. Then they heard a metallic sound and followed it to a factory with a large machine that was creating robots out of the metallic raw material from the mound. As far as I recall, the robots were cylindrical, like missiles with appendages for arms and legs. The robots were moved to the other side of the cave via a non-stopping conveyer belt, where an outlet led to a lengthy, broken bridge. All of the robots fall continuously into a steep cliff, which was now filled with millions of them. The astronaut pressed a major switch, which stopped the production process. At the opposite end of the bridge, there appeared to be another factory.

The astronaut and the AI robot walked across the robot graveyard, only to discover at the other end of the cliff that there was a weapons factory and armament. Then, unexpectedly, a large corroded armored robot (about 20 feet tall) working as a sentinel or guard attempted to confront them, but it was too feeble and said something in a language unknown to the astronaut and the AI robot.

The only thing I recall from the end of the story is that the astronaut and robot deactivated the magnetic field and, as they left the planet, witnessed the mound's door begin to close.